# Unwind segue to a variable scene

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I currently have a tab bar controller with two tabs. Each tab has a button "post", which segues into a new scene. In this 'post scene', there is an option to go back. However, defining the return button to a singular method between the two tabs, `@IBAction func unwindToSegue (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {}`, prohibits it from going back to the other option. How can I have two scenes that point to the same scene and have one unwind segue?

Comment: You can't. A segue, any type of segue, is a particular connection between 2 specific view controllers. Is there a reason you're using an unwind segue, as opposed to calling dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: (popViewControllerAnimated: if you're using a navigation controller)?

Comment: Before you go any further with your coding, I would suggest that you read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".